# HorizontalScrollView display the views of the same size that the screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView with 3 ImageView. I need to have the images of the same width that the screen.

Can you help me please ?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                   android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to android:layout_width="match_parent" in every ImageView and your LinearLayout, HorizontalScrollView

Comment: Won't it introduce a circular dependency with the `<LinearLayout>` parent having `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Comment: Well, no, if you put it to match_parent, the container will wrap at full width. But since you are putting it to match_parent, you can put also put your container at match_parent to avoid it from calculating its width.

Comment: @TyMarc but the parent of the these image views (linearlayout) is the direct child of horizontal scrollview and therefore cannot really have its width set to 'match_parent'.

Comment: Nothing change with

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm also satisfy with **'Stanislav Parkhomenko'**. If you need to have the images of same width of the screen, then change the value with android:layout_width="match_parent" in HorizontalScrollView as well as in every ImageView. That's all.

Comment: The above looks more like a comment. Use the 'answer' section only for [possibly] legitimate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since, screen width will vary across different devices, one of the ways you can achieve this is setting the width at runtime. For getting the screen width appropriately, we can use a `ViewTreeObserver`. Following is the xml file for the test that I derived from your layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that I gave the `android:id="@+id/ll"` property to the layout containing the `ImageView`s. Now for the Java code, we can implement the `ViewTreeObserver` and set width accordingly at runtime:

```
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = ll.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            int width = ll.getWidth();
            View child;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

            for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                child = ll.getChildAt(i);
                params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

                params.width = width;
                child.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

This should do it. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks, the imagesViews are centered but they do not take up the whole width of the screen, there is a margin on each side.

Comment: @DamienDuflot each side? That shouldn't be. Maybe it has to do with the images? Can you post a screenshot?